# What is the difference in usage between the pairs 依然/仍然 and 依旧/仍旧?

Tags: meaning, difference

As in the ones with 然 and 旧

Very hard to tell from example sentences

他仍旧住在那老房子里。 He still lived in the old house.
他仍然住在那条街上。 He is still living on that street.

有些问题仍旧没有解决。 Some problems remain to be solved.
我仍然相信他是无辜的。 I still believe he's innocent.

etc...

Is it that one is relative to a shorter time and one is relative to a longer time?

Comment: see dictionaries,below also see comparison with 还是, bkrs：依然 still; as before:  依旧：as before; still（照旧） (依然,依旧 as interchangeable as "still" and "as before",transposition of "still" and "as before"  may  explain any difference rather well, 旧 being very specific, 然  being a general suffix)
 **仍然**  ：still; yet; as usual; as before; notwithstanding（虽遭抗议，他仍然坚持下去，）  **仍旧** ： remain the same; continue to be; as before（仍然） still; yet (juxtaposition similar to 依然/旧，except combined with 仍"yet, still, as ever; again; keep -ing, continuing").

Comment: ＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂：  **依旧**  （副）有＂仍旧、照样＂的意思。表示情况和原来一样，没有改变。用于书面。**依然**  （副）跟＂依旧＂意思一样。表示动作行为跟原来的一样，没有改变。**仍旧、仍然**  （副）［indicating continuity or resumption of a situation]still; yet,＊[比较］还是｜仍然：＂还是＂和＂仍然＂都是副词，都有表示某种情况持续不变的意思，修饰动词、形容词。但＂还是＂多用于口语，＂仍然＂多用于书面。＂还是＂后边可以跟名词和代词，＂仍然＂不行。＂还是＂表示建议和劝告，＂仍然＂没有这个用法。＂还是＂也表示＂比较后的选择＂有＂最好是＂的意思，＂仍然＂没有这个意思。(1)今天老师还是／仍然给我们讲＂把＂字句的用法。（２）多年不见，你还是／仍然这么年轻。（３）天气预报说今天还是／仍然有雨。（４）今年还是／★仍然王老师教我们。（可以说：今年仍然是王老师教我们）（５）好象要变天，你还是/★仍然带上雨衣吧。（６）A：我想去中国留学，你说去北京好呢还是去天津好？B：还是/★仍然去北京吧。

Comment: preceding comments seem to miss the point, Q seems not to be concerned about difference resulting from that of  2nd characters 染、旧, only that resulting from 1st ones,依、仍，what follows is (mainly) addressed to that difference. ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂ **仍（副）／仍旧（副）／仍然（副）**  **［相同]**  都是副词，作状语，表示某种情况持续不变。可以呼唤：（１）经理了这么多事，我们仍是好朋友。（仍旧✓仍然✓）（２）说了很长时间，父母仍不同意我单独去旅行。（仍旧✓仍然✓）（３）毕业这么多年，林静仍旧保持着读书做笔记的好习惯。（仍✓仍然✓）（４）故乡家门前的小河仍旧那么清澈。（仍✓仍然✓）（５）几年没见，刘芳仍然那么漂亮。（仍✓仍旧✓）（６）虽然已经到了秋天，但是这棵树的叶子仍然这么绿。（仍✓仍旧✓） **［不同］**  ＂仍＂的书面语色彩较强，较少用于口语；＂仍旧、仍然＂口语和书面语都用，＂仍然＂更常用。 **仍然（副）／依然（副；形）／依旧（副；形）**  **［相同］**

Comment: 都是副词，作状语，表示事物或情况跟原来一样，没有改变。有时可以互换：（１）老师批评李强几次，他仍然上课迟到。（依旧✓依然✓）（２）几年没见，安娜仍然那么漂亮。（依旧✓依然✓）（３）虽然这次失败了，但小王依然充满了信心。（仍然✓依旧✓）（４）虽然已经１０月了，可不知为什么天气依然炎热。（仍然✓依旧✓）（５）他出国留学几年后，依旧回到我们公司工作。（仍然✓依然✓）（６）爷爷已经年过七十，可行动依旧非常敏捷。（仍然✓依然✓） **［不同］**  **１。** ＂依然＂可以构成一些固定短语，＂仍然、依旧＂没有这样的用法：☐依然故我 依然如故（仍然✗依旧✗）（１）虽然被老师批评了几次，小张依然故我，没有任何改变。（仍然✗依旧✗）（２）多年后，他回到家乡，家乡依然如故。（仍然✗依旧✗） **２。**  ＂依然、依旧＂还可以作谓语，＂仍然＂没有这种用法：（１）风景依然，人决已不同。（依旧✓仍然✗）（２）这位著名女演员虽然年近五十，但风采依然。（依旧✓仍然✗）（３）青山依旧，绿水长流。（依然✓仍然✗） **３.**  ＂仍然＂口语、书面语都用，多用于叙述性语言中；＂依然、依旧＂一般用于书面语的描写中。

Comment: I was interested in 然 and 旧. Please don't spam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

仍旧 means 'still (**as always**/ same as the past)'

依旧/仍旧 is more specific term for 'still'. It express something '**stay the same despite passing of time** '

> Example 1 : 五十年过去了, 他仍旧住在那条街上 (fifty years is a long time)
>
> Example 2 : 三年过去了, 我仍旧相信他是无辜的 (three years have passed, nothing changed, I still believe he is innocent)

仍然 means 'still (**despite of**)'

依然/仍然 is more general term for 'still'. It express something '**stay the same despite any opposing force or reason**'

> Example 3 : 五十年过去了, 他仍然住在那条街上 (despite the fact that many things would had been changed in 50 years)
>
> Example 4 : 尽管有这么多证据,我仍然相信他是无辜的 (despite the fact that all the evidences are against him, I still believe he is innocent)

- *仍旧/依旧 is actually a shortened form of 依然如旧 / 仍然如旧(still like always/ still like before/ still like in the past)
- *Although they can be used interchangeably sometimes, they are not synonyms.*

Answer (score -1):

Joining @Levin, I deem them identical (仍然=仍旧). Both are old-fashioned. A more colloquial term is 還是 (lit. remain to be).

Comment: according to  ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂ (cf. comments #3,4) differences amount to（１） 依然 （unlike 仍然、依旧、仍旧）can be used in some fixed phrases (固定短语),namely 依然故我、依然如故（２）依然、依旧 （unlike 仍然／旧）can be used as predicative adjectives (3) 仍然／旧 are used in both spoken and written language, 依然／旧mainly in written descriptions, for differences with 还是 see comment #2